# Epidemic, ahhhhhhhhhh!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus

A great plague has hit us, we don't know it's name.

This image will help us find out:

> [image]

Although unlikely, this may be more useful:

> It was headline news from **`@)!`**: 1, 2, 3 after man.

## What is the name of the disease?

Comment: Are you sure riddle is even appropriate tag for this?! Riddles require words. I believe you mean rebuses.

Comment: Than whats the whole point of the image?

Comment: I plead the 5th

Comment: Well, blue eggs are the result of a specific retrovirus according to popsci

Answer (score 10):

## New Answer

> Ebola

Found

> Using Rot13 on Robyn (from nathoenk)

Comment: Yes, but now to solve the other clue.

Answer (score 10):

Partial answer

> The picture is American **Robin** egg.
>  since `I` crossed out and `Y` added.
>  could it be lead to [Robyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robyn).

Comment: So close so close

Answer (score 1):

Based off the work of QuantumTwinkie and nathoenk and the overall tone of the riddle, is it:

> Fear-bola

as coined in

> [Source material:  CNN link](http://www.cnn.com/2014/10/20/health/ebola-overreaction/index.html)